# put download in service for download in background

Tags: android

I am using [this](https://github.com/koush/ion) library for download
it works well but i want download my file in background i don't want use AsyncTask because it has so much code and my project is long .
so help me to download in background with this lib
this is my code :

```
Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
    .load("http://example.com/pdf.zip") // file address
    .progress(new ProgressCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {


            


            progressBar.setProgress((int) downloaded);
            progressBar.setMax((int) total);

            
        }
    })
    .write(new File(direct + File.separator + "signal.zip")) //saving location
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, File result) {




            
            btn24.setText("show");

            btn24.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Card.this, Show.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


    }

});
```

and this is my activity code :

```
 import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.koushikdutta.async.future.FutureCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.Ion;
import com.koushikdutta.ion.ProgressCallback;
import org.zeroturnaround.zip.ZipUtil;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class Card extends AppCompatActivity {

    
    private Button btn1;



    private ProgressBar progresBar;
    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card);

        //getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.toolbar_back_ltr);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });


        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.bar);
        



       
       





        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        


        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Card.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Card.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Card.this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        1);
            } else {
            //do something
        }
    } else {
        //do something
    }




   
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/S/A");

if (!direct.exists()) {
    direct.mkdirs();
}


btn1.setText("Downloading . . .");
Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load("http://example.com/pdf.zip") // file address
        .progress(new ProgressCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {

                

                progressBar.setProgress((int) downloaded);
                progressBar.setMax((int) total);


            }
        })
        .write(new File(direct + File.separator + "AmarVAEhtemal.zip")) // saving location
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, File result) {





                
                btn1.setText("show");

                btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Card.this, Show.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });


            }

        });





                }
            });


        } 

    }
```

Comment: Use Intentservice

Comment: an async task is at most 4 methods, thats not a lot of code

Comment: @WillEvers can I put methods in another class and in main class pass parameters to them for download (for using less code)

Comment: @majidfallah , i cant see that the size of your code is lesser than the AsyncTask :)

Comment: @majidfallah where do you use this code?

Comment: @Vyacheslav when button is clicked i want download a simple file , i am new in android , i don't know what to do , plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use foreground service to protect your progress being killed.

1. use `startService` to start service
2. use `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);` to prevent from desctroying.
3. use your lib.
4. PROFIT!

start service:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
startService(intent);`

service class:

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // The service is being created
showForegroundNotification("some service");
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // The service is starting, due to a call to startService()
        return mStartMode;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // A client is binding to the service with bindService()
        return mBinder;
    }
    @Override

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // The service is no longer used and is being destroyed
    }

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private void showForegroundNotification(String contentText) {
        // Create intent that will bring our app to the front, as if it was tapped in the app
        // launcher
        Intent showTaskIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyMainActivity.class);
        showTaskIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        showTaskIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        showTaskIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                showTaskIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
}
```

start foreground example

https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/6211176

`androidManifest.xml`

```
<service android:name=".ExampleService" . . . >
        </service>
```

put pass extrad data use with:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
intent.putExtra("MYPARAMNAME","MYURL");
startService(intent);`

to retrieve use this:

```
onStartCommand(Intent intent, ...
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
filename = extras.getString("MYPARAMNAME");
```

Comment: I am new in android

Comment: thank you so much , in  onStartCommand i have to download ? how to pass link ?

Comment: oh , i just understand that my library in also download in background and cash files but i have still problem with putting progressBar active in background